# Laravel Permissions on Windows For Saving in Public Path

Tags: laravel, windows-10, file-permissions, intervention

I am using intervention image to save images to the public path in a laravel project. My code is as follows

```
Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path($path . $filename ) );
```

I have ensured that the directory exists yet still receive an error 
`Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path`
I have found various ways to fix this in a linux environment with chown however I see none for windows. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this before you save your image

```
   if (!is_dir($path)) {
        \File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0755, true, true);
    }
```

but if you need best solution you need to use

```
\Storage::disk('public')->put(your_path,$image);
```

Comment: this because you don't have this folder so it didn't find it

Comment: I already have exactly that code, I said the directory exists

Comment: `$path = public_path('assets/staff/images/');` In laravel the public_path method refers to the public directory in the project root The final parameter used in save() is `(C:\Users\james\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\xsc\storage\C:\Users\james\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\xsc\storage\assets/staff/images/gfhgf-1563742815.png)`

Comment: i know that can you print what is the result of this `$path . $filename`

Comment: i think you have problem here

 `->save( public_path($path . $filename ) )`

you need to make it just like this

 `->save($path . $filename )`

Comment: i see, can you try what i wrote to you in last comment

Comment: That works. I guess it was the double public_path causing problems. If you ammend your answer ill mark it correct.

Comment: yes i saw that when you sent result of `$path` hope i helped you,can you make it as right answer

Answer (score 1):

that error doesn't mean you need permission , especially in windows environment

that means you send invalid path parameter (directory not existed)

lets say $path like this

```
$path = 'assets/uploads';
```

and then $filename like this

```
$filename = 'foo.bar';
```

last part for saving the image

```
Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path($path . '/' . $filename ) );
```

Comment: I think the path is correct. The error shows it as `(C:\Users\james\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\xsc\storage\C:\Users\james\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\xsc\storage\assets/staff/images/gfhgf-1563742815.png)`

Comment: how can you assume that's the correct path ?
thats totally wrong
the correct one should only
C:\Users\james\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\xsc\storage\assets/staff/images/gfhgf-1563742815.png)

Comment: the error show up because you define public path twice first on $path = as public_path('assets/staff/images')
then you define it again on ->save( public_path($path))
just try my answer, then you won't encounter error again